# runtime error -2147220992(80040200) trying to debug a VB6 application

Tags: vb6, ado

I have received a image of a working environment where VB6 is installed.
In here there is some sw I am supposed to convert to a more modern technology but nevertheless it would be convenient to be able to debug that old code to really find out what is going on.

The visual Basic IDE starts up, albeit it is trying to install Microsoft office 2000 premium for some strange reason, which I have to cancel several times.

Then when I press the run button, again, the install of Microsoft office 2000 premium kicks in, again I have to cancel, but I end up in a runtime error :
Run-time error -2147220992(80040200), method 'rsMyset' of object '_DataMaster' failed.

This error seems to indicate something is missing, but what is missing I have no clue. The point in the code where the error occurs is at the point it is trying to access the database.

```
With MyDE.rsMyset

    If .State = 1 Then
        .Close
    End If
```

This MyDE thing is a DataEnvironment of good old ADO. 
underneith there is a MasterConnect which is a DEConnection.
The property that matters for this MasterConnect is ConnectionSource = file name=data.udl
this rsMyset is a resultSet of Myset which is a DECommand also of good old ADO.
The system is running on windows XP SP2 and MDAC is installed so ADO should be present.

It would be really nice if I could get this freaking error solved so that I can find out more easily what the code is doing by inspecting variables and the like.
I did not create this Sw, it is way old, and the person who created it does not really have any time to help either. Frankly I think he does not know how to solve these problems either. It worked for him in the past and now it does not, or he never debugged the darn thing.

Any help appreciated more specifically :

- how can i find out what is not registered properly (that is what the error seams to point out to)
- how can i remove the error.
- is installing the office 2000 premium the solution to this ?
- I just did something 'drastic' , i cleared the value of the ConnectionSource of the DEConnection that is being used. If I then start the application, I have to fill in the properties of my database manually 2 times, but then the application starts up. Strange because this either means that the udl file is wrong which is strange because without the debugger it starts with this udl file. But at least now I have an option, albeit tedious, to do some debugging.

Comment: In the IDE, check Project>References to see if there are any missing references.  Does the app use an MS Access database?

Comment: It uses a SQL server database to which it connects via a udl file

Comment: The DataEnvironment was always a bit hard to debug, and I avoided it almost as religiously as the Data Control.  You might consider replacing the DE code with straight ADO objects (the DE was a "more user-friendly" somewhat visual wrapper for ADO), unless they are sprinkled everywhere.